# Zoom (center) map to markers in OpenLayer3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have problem with my OpenLayer3 map. When I add some markers to map I want to resize my map and change the zoom so that all markers were set on the screen.

My code looks like:

```
/** CREATE MARKERS **/
for (var i=0;i<1;i++){
  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new
      ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([Math.random()*360-180, Math.random()*180-90], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857'))
  });
  vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
  var newBound = ol.Bounds();
  newBound.extend([Math.random()*360-180, Math.random()*180-90]);
  map.zoomToExtent(newBound);
}

/** MARKER STYLE **/
var iconStyle = [
  new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 0.07,
    src: 'marker.png'
  }))
  })
];

/** ADD LAYER VECTOR **/
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: iconStyle
});


/** INIT MAP **/
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  overlays: [overlay],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

Is there a way to zoom the map to markers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some errors in your logic and in some OL references. First you should create an ol.Extent that contains all the markers. Then use the map's view to fit it in.

```
// create ten random markers
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var point = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([Math.random() * 50, Math.random() * 50], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: point
    });

    vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
}


// make the map's view to zoom and pan enough to display all the points
map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
```

Here's a plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/KVL14vdOSqJBxZz44s3u?p=preview

Comment: Ok, I would test this solution

Comment: Please @kagelos, check Your answer because sometimes zoom cut some points.

Comment: You mean after you zoom in manually or initially the map doesn't contain all the points?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes when I load this script some markers don't show on map.

Comment: @mdk can you provide an example of the problem?

Comment: Hmm, sometimes map set too much zoom, but I dont know why.. :(

Comment: @mdk Have you noticed this in my reply (plunker code) or in your code?

Comment: Stupid me to admit, but the problem was on the side CSS classes. Thank you once again for taking the problem and solve it! :)
PS. If You have some extra time please look for my new question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385837/show-popup-window-on-marker-in-openlayers3

Answer (score 0):

Once your vector features has been drawn you may get the extent using:

```
vector.on('render',function(e){
var myextent = vector.getSource().getExtent();
})
```

And then you may zoom to this extent using:

```
map.getView().fit(myextent , map.getSize());
```

So if you are going to use the `render` event

```
vector.on('render',function(e){
map.getView().fit(vector.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
})
```